# PostgresSQL: Using Where Clause on Unnest with Existing Join

Tags: postgresql, join, unnest

I've worked hard to overcome some data formatting issues with this query but can't wrap my mind around how to limit the month column from the unnest to exclude future dates. The source table includes future data that is unreliable so I want to exclude it.

```
select fbr.organization, fbr.year, a.accounttype, unnest(array[concat(year,'0101'), concat(year,'0201'), concat(year,'0301'), concat(year,'0401'), concat(year,'0501'), concat(year,'0601'), concat(year,'0701'), concat(year,'0801'), concat(year,'0901'), concat(year,'1001'), concat(year,'1101'), concat(year,'1201')])::date as month, unnest(array[sum(jan), sum(feb), sum(mar), sum(apr), sum(may), sum(jun), sum(jul), sum(aug), sum(sep), sum(oct), sum(nov), sum(dec)]) AS balance from fundbalancereport as fbr
left join account as a on a.accountnumber = split_part(text,' ',1) and a.organization = fbr.organization
where year > 2018
and left(text,1) = '1'
and accounttype = 'Bank'
group by fbr.organization, fbr.year, a.accounttype
```

This yields the exact format I need, something like:

```
"organization","year","accounttype","month","balance"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-01-01","500.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-02-01","550.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-03-01","650.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-04-01","450.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-05-01","450.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-06-01","450.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-07-01","450.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-08-01","450.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-09-01","450.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-10-01","450.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-11-01","450.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-12-01","450.00000"
```

Ideally I would like to add a where clause of month is less than or equal to today which should yield:

```
"organization","year","accounttype","month","balance"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-01-01","500.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-02-01","550.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-03-01","650.00000"
"org1",2020,"Bank","2020-04-01","450.00000"
```

I read through this q: [How to add where clause with unnest in sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211749/how-to-add-where-clause-with-unnest-in-sql-query)

But when I tried to add the additional SELECT I got an error that multiple rows were returned so I am a little lost from here since I already have an existing join that I need.

I tried:

```
select fbr.organization, fbr.year, a.accounttype, 
(select unnest(array[concat(year,'0101'), concat(year,'0201'), concat(year,'0301'), concat(year,'0401'), concat(year,'0501'), concat(year,'0601'), concat(year,'0701'), concat(year,'0801'), concat(year,'0901'), concat(year,'1001'), concat(year,'1101'), concat(year,'1201')])::date as month), (select unnest(array[sum(jan), sum(feb), sum(mar), sum(apr), sum(may), sum(jun), sum(jul), sum(aug), sum(sep), sum(oct), sum(nov), sum(dec)]) AS balance) from fundbalancereport as fbr
left join account as a on a.accountnumber = split_part(text,' ',1) and a.organization = fbr.organization
where year > 2018
and left(text,1) = '1'
and accounttype = 'Bank'
group by fbr.organization, fbr.year, a.accounttype
```

and got

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Any guidance would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you added the additional SELECT in the wrong place.  Please show us what you did.

Comment: @jjanes I am sure you're right. Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `unnest` from `select` part

```
select unnest(array['20190101'::date, '20200101'::date, '20210101'::date]) d
```

to `from` part of a query and add `where` part

```
select d
from unnest(array['20190101'::date, '20200101'::date, '20210101'::date]) d
where d<=now()
```

Edit:

I believe you want to unpivot data, in that case your query could be:

```
select fbr.organization, fbr.year, a.accounttype, fbr.month, sum(fbr.val) as balance
from
  (
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0101')::date as month, jan as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0201')::date as month, feb as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0301')::date as month, mar as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0401')::date as month, apr as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0501')::date as month, may as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0601')::date as month, jun as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0701')::date as month, jul as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0801')::date as month, aug as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'0901')::date as month, sep as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'1001')::date as month, oct as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'1101')::date as month, nov as val from fundbalancereport union
    select organization, year, text, concat(year,'1201')::date as month, dec as val from fundbalancereport
  ) fbr
left join account as a on a.accountnumber = split_part(text,' ',1) and a.organization = fbr.organization
where year > 2018
and left(text,1) = '1'
and accounttype = 'Bank'
group by fbr.organization, fbr.year, a.accounttype, fbr.month
```

Comment: Edited my question as I tried something similar and got an error. Do you mind editing your answer to include more context into how that fits into the entire query?

Comment: Yes! That is perfect except for the need to add the month where clause
`and fbr.month < now()` which did the trick.